# Is it real to dynamically define width of image by his URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to define width of image before it loads as **background-image** property of `DIV`?

```
function nn() {
  if (arr !== null) {
    var el = document.getElementById("n");
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = arr[x];
    el.style.width = img.width;
    el.style.backgroundImage = arr[x];
  }
}

$(window).on({
  load: function() {
    resizeBind(width);
    nn(arr);
    return width;
  }
});
```

Where `arr[]` has few URLs of images?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to load the image into the `img` tag, wait its `load` event, and only then query for the image properties:

```js
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.classList.add("obj");
img.src = "http://www.parisilabs.com/colors2/images/30892183_350_350.jpg";
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log("Width:%d Height:%d", document.getElementById('test').width,
    document.getElementById('test').height);
}, false);
img.id = "test";
document.getElementById("content").appendChild(img);
```

```html
<div id="content" />
```